# Node::load() with specific revision ID

Tags: 8, entities

I want to load the node details for a specific revision. I tried using the following code.

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
$nid = 1171;
$vid = 9423;
$rev_node = Node::load($nid, $vid, TRUE);
```

I also tried the following code.

```
$rev_node = node_load($nid, $vid);
```

It always loads the latest version, irrespective of the revision ID passed to the method/function call.

Is there a way to load the data for a specific revision?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadRevision($vid);
```

Comment: but there is no **$node_id** specified in this right ??

Comment: Not working actually

Comment: There are no need of node ID because revision id is a unique id and will associate with only one node only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
$node = node_load($node_id);
\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->revisionIds($node);
```

to get the revision IDs for a node.

You can then load a specific revision of a node with `$rev = node_revision_load($rev_id);`

Comment: It actually prints out large array unlike a **node_load**

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `entityManager()` is deprecated in Drupal 8: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityManager/8.5.x, so, instead, you could use `entityTypeManager()`:

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadRevision($revision_id);
```